# PyDev/Python3.1 Subprocess Error - no encoding declared

Tags: python, encoding, subprocess, pydev

When I run **Parent.py** which calls the subprocess child.exe the following error occurs

```
  File "child.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file child.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

If I run the Parent.py with **child.py**, the execution successfully returns 'Hello from parent.' from Eclipse.

If I run Parent.py from the shipped IDLE nothing is returned in the case of both child.exe and child.py

I have read the http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ documentation and understood it, possibly missunderstood it to mean I should add the suggested comments which I have tried adding to child.exe ... they did not work.


**Parent.py**

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import msvcrt
    import _subprocess
else:
    import fcntl

# Create pipe for communication
pipeout, pipein = os.pipe()

# Prepare to pass to child process
if sys.platform == "win32":
    curproc = _subprocess.GetCurrentProcess()
    pipeouth = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(pipeout)
    pipeoutih = _subprocess.DuplicateHandle(curproc, pipeouth, curproc, 0, 1,
            _subprocess.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)

    pipearg = str(int(pipeoutih))  
else:
    pipearg = str(pipeout)

    # Must close pipe input if child will block waiting for end
    # Can also be closed in a preexec_fn passed to subprocess.Popen
    fcntl.fcntl(pipein, fcntl.F_SETFD, fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC)

# Start child with argument indicating which FD/FH to read from
subproc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'child.exe', pipearg], close_fds=False)

# Close read end of pipe in parent
os.close(pipeout)
if sys.platform == "win32":
    pipeoutih.Close()

# Write to child (could be done with os.write, without os.fdopen)
pipefh = os.fdopen(pipein, 'w')
pipefh.write("Hello from parent.")
pipefh.close()

# Wait for the child to finish
subproc.wait()
```

**Child.exe** (frozen with cx_freeze)

```
import os, sys


if sys.platform == "win32":
    import msvcrt

# Get file descriptor from argument
pipearg = int(sys.argv[1])
if sys.platform == "win32":
    pipeoutfd = msvcrt.open_osfhandle(pipearg, 0)
else:
    pipeoutfd = pipearg

# Read from pipe
# Note:  Could be done with os.read/os.close directly, instead of os.fdopen
pipeout = os.fdopen(pipeoutfd, 'r')
print(pipeout.read())
pipeout.close()
```

Comment: Whats the encoding from your eclipse editor? it doesn't seem to be either ascii, nor utf-8. It also doenst' seem to be ut-16 because of the missing Byte Order Mark(BOM). Could you look up your standrad editor encoding ?

Comment: I'm not 100% I'm looking the the right place, but if i go Edit -> Set Encoding - > It is set to **Default (inherited from container: Cp1252)** It also has an option to select other types such as UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'child.exe', pipearg], ...
```

The problem is that you are trying to make python read a binary file, if child.exe is a normal windows executable. The error raises because the bytes of the binary files are out of the standard ascii - utf8 standard so the interpreter can't read it.

Maybe what you want is to just execute the child.exe just remove the python line from it:

```
subprocess.Popen(['child.exe', pipearg], ...
```